# Conversion from const char * to const std::string &

Tags: c++

I think following code should generate an error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

static void pr(const std::string &aStr)
{
    std::cout << aStr << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "Hellu";

    pr(a);

    return 0;
}
```

But gcc 4.1.2 compiles it successuflly.

Is it that the constructor of std::string get in the way, creating an instance of std::string?

I believe it shouldn't, because reference is merely an alias to a variable (in this case, there is no variable of type std::string that the reference is referring to).

Is anybody out there to explain why the code compiles successfully?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you encounter is implicit conversion.

Here is a quote from the C++ Standard (SC22-N-4411.pdf)

> 1 Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors and by conversion functions. These conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for **implicit** type conversions (Clause 4), for initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).

So the compiler just works as intended and calls the `std::string` constructor you mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, given a reference to a *constant*, the compiler can/will synthesize a temporary (in this case of type `std::string`) and bind the reference to that temporary.

If the reference was not to a const object, however, that wouldn't work -- only a reference to const can bind to a temporary object like that (though at least widely used compiler allows a non-const reference to bind to a reference as well).

Comment: Interessting facts. One is learning everyday ;). I didnt get your second sentence right though. Do you mean if the function header would be `void pr(std::string &aStr)` a construction of a temporary (by implying) is not possible by the standart?

Comment: @Paranaix: Correct -- `pr(std::string &)` would not be able to accept a temporary object.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, then, is there any way to keep the compiler from making a temp instance?

Comment: @orchistro You want to call the operator<< method of the temporary object, don't you?

Comment: @orchistro, just curious: why do you want to prevent the implicit conversion?

Comment: @orchistro What do you want to happen instead of the temporary? Compile error? If you provide another function overload that doesn't require creation a temporary, that will be called instead.

Comment: I just want compiler to generate an error, but there seems to be no way to do that (is case of gcc), I'll just live with that.

Comment: @FrederickRoch, I was refactoring legacy code which have many funcs with args of `const char*` where they call `strlen()`. I thought the needless loops will disappear by changing them to accept `const string&` instead of `const char*`. And this problem popped up. The callers will still be handing `const char*` over to the legacy funcs I already have modified to accept `const string&`. I thought the compiler would generate error for func type mismatch so that I could take care of callers, which turned out to be false. Now, I am stuck with callers still calling legacy funcs with `cosnt char*`.

Comment: @orchistro: It seems to me that the obvious answer would be to temporarily modify the functions to take references to non-const `std::string`, so the compiler will reject anything that tries to pass a `char *` or `char const *`. I'd probably use a typedef to make it relatively quick and easy to switch the argument type.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, It is a brilliant idea! Unfortunately, I've already done it in stupid way, thanks.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann FYI, I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/34527269/1085251. It explains why 'non-const' references are not allowed to be bound to temporaries. Hope it helps.